# How do I get the latlng (gps) coordinates of the magnification pane in using the Street View api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am not sure if this is possible or not; but I would like to do is get the gps coordinates of the magnification pane (- I think this the name for it? It is usually represented by a semi-transparent rectangle or an oval, please see the picture below) in Google's Street View:

http://tinypic.com/r/5jy8n6/6

The panel moves around street view on mouse move, and renders itself next to buildings, walls or the road.

Ideally I'd like to bind to a mouse move event and get the position of the magnification pane, but after reading through the API it doesn't look like that is possible.

I can get the lat and lang coordinates from the panorama by adding a listener for 'position_changed' event on the panorama:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function(  ) {
     console.log( 'position', panorama.getPosition() );
 });
```

I can also get the heading and pitch information by listening to pov_changed:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'pov_changed', function( ) {

    console.log( 'pov', panorama.getPov() );
});
```

I am using Google Maps Javascript API V3.

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE ====>
If I view the source that is generated by the panorama and open the SVG object I can see two objects that are modified when the mouse is moved. An Ellipse object which represents the panel on the road:

```
<ellipse fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" visibility="hidden" fill-opacity="0.5" cx="658" cy="223" rx="30" ry="5"></ellipse>
```

And a path object which represents the panel on the building or wall.

```
<path fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" visibility="hidden" fill-opacity="0.5" d="M400 53 L402 -22 L299 -65 L296 24 Z"></path>
```

So I could potentially find the dimensions of the pane, but not sure if I can use this information to find the position of the pane from the users current position.

Comment: What is the reason for not using the two events?

Comment: @SalmanA, because the events are not giving the position I require. Sorry I don't think I explained it well. I have added a picture to help clarify: http://tinypic.com/r/5jy8n6/6 
I would like the get the position of the semi-transparent rectangle in the image. The rectangle moves with the mouse and pins itself to buildings and roads. So, essentially in that example ,I would like to know the GPS position of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any details about this pane.

This pane is a part of a flash-layer, as long as it doesn't expose any details for the pane, you will not be able to get the position. 
Mouse-events wouldn't help here, because you don't know the distance of the object where the pane is applied to.

Comment: I don't think it is a flash layer? If I view the source generated by the panorama, and open the svg that gets created I can see two objects that get drawn on mouse move: one eclipse obj for the circle on the road and a path obj for the walls and buildings. So I could work out the dimensions of the pane. Just not its position.

Comment: for me it's a flash-object above the complete map, checked in FF,Chrome,Opera